# Update a datetime field with 1 minute older time in pro *C

Tags: c, oracle, datetime, solaris

We have implemented the following query in **pro *C** with Oracle database, which works properly.

```
update anp
set lssn = :ssn,
ltd = :td;
```

Here ltd is a datetime field and td is a datetime variable. Now we want to implement this query in such a way that ltd will be updated with 1 min lesser time from td.
Example:
If td has a value **2014-01-02 14:44:03**, ltd should be updated with **2014-01-02 14:43:03**.

I have tried many things like:

```
update anp
set lssn = :ssn,
ltd = :td -(1/1440);

update anp
set lssn = :ssn,
ltd = :td + interval '-60'  second;
```

And many things but I failed to achieve it. Please help me.

Comment: Can you please show the declaration of `:td` ?

Comment: Your statements seem correct and should work. How exactly do they fail?

Comment: Also, failed you mean, any error or wrong data?

Comment: @MaheswaranRavisankar-`EXEC SQL BEGIN DECLARE SECTION;
    dtime_t td;
EXEC SQL END DECLARE SECTION;`

Comment: @Thorsten Kettner- which one?

Comment: @MaheswaranRavisankar - first one gives PL/SQL found semantic errors during compilation

Comment: @Thorsten Kettner- second one give 30081 error in run time.

Comment: You'll need to convert `:td` to an actual `date` first. How is the `dtime_t` type defined - why do you have your own type for dates at all? (You know `date` includes times down to second precision, right, and `timestamp` exists if you need greater precisin than that?)

Comment: you can see the `.c` and check how this statement is framed. Looks like the problem with `dtime_t`. `30081` error is because, of the date unrecognised or invalid.

Comment: @AlexPoole- Can you tell me the declaretion of TD as date datatype

Comment: Sorry, it's been a while, I was thinking the declare section had Oracle types but of course it doesn't. What is `dtime_t` - a structure, a string, a `varchar` with `.arr` set to `2014-01-02 14:44:03`? If your first query works then it must be something Oracle can recognise but it looks like you're doing an implicit conversion.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It looks like `td` is a string representation of a date, so `dtime_t` seems to be a structure - possibly a `VARCHAR`. If so, you're doing an implicit date conversion at the moment, which isn't a good idea anyway as it relies on the NLS settings of the client application; which are maybe controlled in a Pro*C app more than in other scenarios, but still a potential failure point. But in this case you're trying to subtract the interval from the *string* before that implicit conversion has happened; hence the ORA-30081 error.

Changing that to an explicit conversion would allow the interval arithmetic:

```
update anp
set lssn = :ssn,
ltd = to_date(:td, 'YYYY-MM-DD HH24:MI:SS') - interval '1' minute;
```

A simple demonstration:

```
select '2014-01-02 14:44:03' - interval '1' minute from dual;

SQL Error: ORA-30081: invalid data type for datetime/interval arithmetic
30081. 00000 -  "invalid data type for datetime/interval arithmetic"
*Cause:    The data types of the operands are not valid for datetime/interval
           arithmetic.
```

Versus:

```
select to_date('2014-01-02 14:44:03', 'YYYY-MM-DD HH24:MI:SS')
  - interval '1' minute from dual;

TO_DATE('2014-01-0214:44:03','YYYY-MM-DDHH24:MI:SS')-INTERVAL'1'MINUTE
----------------------------------------------------------------------
2014-01-02 14:43:03
```

Comment: Thanks for help. How can we do same thing in the informix?

Comment: @1053588 - I'm not familiar with informix, but it [has a `to_date` function too](http://pic.dhe.ibm.com/infocenter/idshelp/v115/index.jsp?topic=%2Fcom.ibm.sqls.doc%2Fids_sqs_1543.htm); so I guess same mechanism, different format model?